# How do I put a newline into an environment variable in an Apache SetEnv directive?

Tags: apache-2.2, environment-variables

I'd like to have a newline character in an environment variable. I've tried

```
SetEnv DI_collection_clients_list "client1
client2"
```

which results in

```
Invalid command 'client2"', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

when restarting Apache.

I've also tried

```
SetEnv DI_collection_clients_list "client1\nclient2"
```

which results in the variable of course having a `\n` instead of a newline.

Answer (score 1):

The [setenv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) directive is part of [mod_env.c](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/modules/metadata/mod_env.c) which uses the [apr](http://apr.apache.org/) function [apr_table_setn](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__tables.html#ga1fe7bb25d4027bb79d3c2bb41d8d8b75) to store the environment variables in a table. If you look at the [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/apr/apr/trunk/tables/apr_tables.c?view=markup) you'll see that the table just stores the data that is passed to it without any character expansion.

Whatever it is you're trying to do, trying to do it this way is almost certainly wrong.